# ngDialog - get maximum height

Tags: css, ng-dialog

I am using ngDialog for my popup windows. I can make it as wide as my whole screen but not as tall. Here is a style I am using:

```
<style>
.ngdialog.dialogcaseeditor .ngdialog-content {
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}    
</style>
```

height: 100%; does not even near give a maximum height.

Somewhere in the code then after a dialog is opened I can say something like this:

```
$dialog.dialog.find('.ngdialog-content').css('height', $window.innerHeight);
```

That will make the the popup window as tall as the whole screen, bu the screen itself will become scrollable, even though the popup does not exceed the screen.
[image]

As you can see, there is a vertical scroll bar on the right side.
Can this scroll issue be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide scroll bars:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Does not look like it's helping. it's not like the popup is scrollable, it's the whole browser window that scrolls.

Comment: have you tried ``overflow: hidden``? and setting the height to maybe 95%?

Comment: overflow: hidden has no effect either. Yes, I can lower the height until it won't scroll, but that is not the point of this exercise. It won't be as near as tall as the screen when I get rid of scrolling.